# How to extend raster edges when rescaled using the warp tool in QGIS

Tags: raster, gdalwarp, resolution

I am rescaling a raster from a resolution of 100m to 2000m using the warp tool (method cubic spline) in QGIS, it looses a lot of information around the edges which I would like to retain. Is there a a setting in the tool, or perhaps a different tool, or a way to do this programmatically in python, to avoid loosing any (or most) information at the edges? In the image below the bottom raster is the 100m resolution, and the top raster is the 2000m resolution, you can see that the top layer doesn't cover all areas that the bottom layer does. I don't need perfect coverage just better than what is shown below.
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I do not quite understand what you mean. Do you think that there are pixels missing from the 2000m version, like the second and third pixels on the second row? I rather believe they have turned into nodata and they are shown as transparent. That could happen if the default resampling method nearest neighbor is used. I would have a try with average or cubic resampling. But I notice now that you used cubic. That is odd. Test data would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not the particular raster that I used that matters, as I tried a few others and the same thing occurs when drastically change the resolution from 100m to 2000m, nor is it the sampling method, I tried a few and they all respond similarly. As I change the resolution from 2000m to 500m it gets a lot better of course. I think the issue is the default method the tool uses for dealing with edges, whether to include to a cell as a value or make it nodata. This is what I would like to alter if at all possible, so that I can include all areas covered by the 100m raster in the 2000m raster.

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand properly what is the exact problem. Could you add sample images: 100m, 2000m version, and if possible, a desired result made with Gimp or whatever tool that you can find.